# Moq: Moq is setup but doesn't think it is called

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have the following class with a Log function that for the testing purpose just returns true.

```
public SomeClass : ILogger
{
    // Other functions

    public bool Log()
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

How ever in my unit test I have the following:

```
 Mock<ILogger> logger = new Mock<ILogger>();
 logger.Setup(func => func.Log()).Returns(() => false).Verifiable();

 SomeClass testMe = new SomeClass(logger.Object);
 bool result = testMe.Log();

 logger.Verify(); //This fails saying that the Log function was never called
```

The bool result is not set to false, but to true. Which leads me to believe my setup is incorrect. Is this the case?

Comment: That is because you haven't called `Log()` method of injected logger instance. Call `logger.Log()` inside your `SomeClass` `Log` method

Comment: Please provide implementation of your method `Log` declared on `SomeClass`. Most likely you do not call the log function of your logger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you haven't called `Log()` method of injected logger instance. Call `logger.Log()` inside your `SomeClass` Log method

```
public SomeClass : ILogger
{
    private ILogger logger;
    // Other functions

    public SomeClass(ILogger logger)
    {
     this.logger = logger;
    }    

    public bool Log()
    {
        return logger.Log();
        //return true;
    }
}
```